# PHP File name numbering

Tags: php, numbers, phpword

I think this question will be really stupid, but I couldn't find answer, and additionally I'm a novice with PHP.

The problem is that I'm using PHPWord, and I was trying to skip MySQL using only PHP and PHPWord to do a **delivery[ID].docx** file, which contains ID, that is adding +1 every file is created e.x.;

- delivery11.docx
- delivery12.docx
- delivery13.docx

My current code load/save looks like this:

```
require_once 'PHPWord.php';
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();
$document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('./dfiles/delivery_template.docx');

     $nm = $_POST['NAME_' . 1];
     $qt = $_POST['QUANTITY_' . 1];
     $iid = $_POST['ID_' . 1];
     $t = 1000;
     $wg = $qt * $t;
     $document->setValue('pn1', $nm);
     $document->setValue('kg1', $wg);

$numid = 1;
$document->save('Delivery G'.$numid++.'-'.date(m).'-'.date(Y).'.docx', './dfiles/');
```

And I know that the **$numid** will set value to 1, when the code will trigger again this function, so please help, how can I do this, without MySQL?

Additionally info: This code will be triggered by **HTML submit** function.

Comment: You can use `file_exists` to check if the file is all ready there (i.e name is taken), then use a loop and if logic to continue adding +1 until you get a name that is free.

Comment: Works. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP variables only last as long as PHP is running - i.e. for the time it takes to generate a response to the request. If you want to reference a value created or modified in a previous execution, you'll need to store that somewhere. You could just use a file:

```
function getNextNumber() 
{
   $number=file_get_contents("/tmp/counter");
   file_put_contents("/tmp/counter", ++$number);
   return $number;
}
```

Which should be OK most of the time on a very low volume server. **But it does not scale!** Sooner or later you will run into contention.

This is *why* we use databases.

It doesn't have to be MySQL (you didn't provide any reason why you couldn't use MySQL which might have been helpful) there are lots of other databases which would be suitable (including SQLite which doesn't require a database server to be running).

Comment: Didn't wanted to use MySQL cause I'm not in any scale familiar with it, so I was searching temporary option. I think it can work about month without any problems. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do in diff ways:

1. Generate some random number and append to file, if file exists then regenerate random number and append to file, Keep do this process until no duplicate files found.
2. You can add date and time, so that it will be unique and readable also.(For eg: Delivery G 10-8-2015[15.12.99].doc)
3. Generate hash code, and append.

Comment: Yea, tried that first options, and it works.
The second one, isn't a way for me, cause anyway I need to know how many delivering is per month. Thanks for answer.

Comment: In 2nd method Delivery G 10-8-2015[HH.MM.SS.miliSec].doc). This will be simple and easy to create. And I much faster than any other method, I guess